# How to establish one to many mapping from two postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a created different tables in two different PostgreSQL DB now i want to establish one to many and one to one relationship between two different DB's table How i can do this using hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

To achive your goal you have to create a DB Link between the two DBs because you only can use realtionship mapping with hibernate with one DB connection.

Please read more about DB link here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html